# PureMVC and Navigation with Silverlight (C#) for Windows Phone 7 (WP7)

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, windows-phone-7, puremvc

I've used PureMVC before with AS3, and am playing around with WP7 so thought it would make sense to try the C# port (http://trac.puremvc.org/PureMVC_CSharp/)

The problem I'm having is that the samples (Login/Employee Admin) don't use the NavigationService to change states within the application - they simply hide/show controls when needed.

Does anyone know of an example of PureMVC with NavigationService or how this might work?

OR should I just give up trying to use PureMVC and learn a new framework like MVVM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PureMVC for C# doesn't contain a port for Windows Phone 7. (The page you provided the link for doesn't list it as a supported platform.) This seems like a good explanation for why it doesn't use the NavigationService.

If you want to use PureMVC you're likely going to have to port it to WP7 yourself or wait for a version to be produced for you. Only you can decide if you want to go down this route.

If you decide you want to look at MVVM, I'd recommend the highly popular [MVVM Light Toolkit.](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/getstarted/)

Comment: Thanks Matt. I appreciate that there is no direct WP7 port, but the Navigation framework is part of Silverlight, and isn't specific to WP7. So in theory the Silverlight version of the port would work (if it supports navigation)? I've been looking at MVVM Light too, thanks.

Comment: @Ian the release notes for PureMVC (http://trac.puremvc.org/PureMVC_CSharp/wiki/ReleaseNotes) only say support for Silverlight 2.0 has been added (even though it lists 2.0, 3.0 & 4.0 as supported platforms). This would explain why there's no NavigationService - as this was added in Silverlight 3.0